# Batch rename a .Blend file after the first Slot Material with Python

Tags: python, materials, scripting

After a data crash I have a couple of thousand files like this "f1288357332.blend". I'm not good at python but there must be a way to rename those files as batch (that are mostly materials) after the name of the material in the first slot of blender.

Until now I have only this:

```
import bpy
import os

#get current filename

filepath = bpy.data.filepath
filepath_split = os.path.split(filepath) #list with [path, name]
```

Comment: what is the logic you want to use for renaming? like f1288357332.blend what is it supposed to be renamed to? EDIT: oh i didnt read the title. XD

Comment: so we can prepare the script assuming you have only 1 mesh object that has only 1 material, or use the material at material index 0.

Comment: The problem is most of the files have a material in it but no mesh. So the material is not even applied somewhere... uff i struggle with the logic.

Comment: ok let me sort that out. i'll update my answer.

Comment: updated my answer. you can use that script, if there is no mesh then it will get the last material in `bpy.data.materiasls`

Comment: Ok iam totally beginner. I start the script from inside blender or from a python environment? The Script is awesome! I try what i can! Thank you!

Comment: oh sorry i totally forgot you have more than just 1 file XD wait let me sort this one out XD but for starters try one file, paste it into [Text Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) which you can find under the Scripting tab and run script just to test if that is the result you want

Comment: I forgot to tell: The files are all in one directory.

Comment: what if they have the same material name? thus they will clash with same blend name. or are you 100% sure the material names are different in each blend file?

Comment: All the blend files have a unique number like this f1288357332.blend. May this structure can stay and the script can give the material name additonal to the file name.

Comment: cool. ok i have updated my answer. please try this with a few files first, maybe 2 or 3 files. so you know its working before you try it on all files because it could take a while depending on how many files you have

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the script. Renaming thousends of files is really time consuming. Really Good Work!

Comment: no problem! happy i was able to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script assumes you have at least 1 object with a mesh which has at least 1 material slot and names the final file by the material name and saves it in a new directory `generated` inside the directory of all your blend files. The first object with material it finds in the loop will be used. If no mesh is found, it will use the last material name in the `bpy.data.materials` list.

Save this script in a separate file as `rename-script.py`

```
import bpy
import os

filepath = bpy.data.filepath
basepath, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
newpath = os.path.join(basepath, "generated")
os.makedirs(newpath,  exist_ok=True)

new_filename = ''

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type != 'MESH' or len(o.material_slots) <= 0:
        continue
    new_filename = os.path.join(newpath, o.material_slots[0].name + ".blend")
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=new_filename)
    break

if new_filename == '':
    print("no mesh found using first material in the materials list")
    idx = len(bpy.data.materials) - 1
    new_filename = os.path.join(newpath, bpy.data.materials[idx].name + ".blend")
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=new_filename)
```

Then open Blender and under the Scripting tab paste the following script into the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html). This script will iterate through all your blend files in the directory you have assigned to variable `BLEND_FILES_DIRECTORY` and save them into a sub directory called `generated`. Make sure the variable `RENAME_SCRIPT` is pointing to wherever you saved your `rename-script.py` file. So you can safely delete `generated` directory if you want to generate your files again.

```
import bpy
import os
import glob
from subprocess import call

BLEND_FILES_DIRECTORY = r"/path/to/your/blend/files" #example path: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\blendfiles
RENAME_SCRIPT = r"/path/to/rename-script.py" #example path: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\blendfiles\rename-script.py

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(BLEND_FILES_DIRECTORY, '*.blend')):
    basepath, filename = os.path.split(file) 
    print("process file:", filename)
    call(['blender','-b', file, '-P', RENAME_SCRIPT])
```

Open your [`System Console`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/advanced/command_line/introduction.html) to see the progress. You can open it by going to *Window > Toggle System Console*.