# How to speed up rendering if I do not care about quality of rendered frames

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I'm rendering auxiliary data such as depth map, optical flow (vector), and normals. I do not care about the quality of the rendered frames. What changes can I do to achieve this? Currently, I'm setting the number of samples to 1, which itself sped up things a lot. But I have 9600 frames to render. Is it possible to speed it even further?

PS: I need to do this via python. That's because I have 200 different blend files and I cannot manually change the settings for each of them.

Comment: you also set it to Eevee? u can easily find the code to set samples via python. just right click the samples field and choose *Copy Full Data Path* then paste in Text Editor and assign 1 to it. then u can do something similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/272449/142292 to loop through all your blend files.

Comment: render at a lower resolution and then scale it up? setting resolution to 50% should speed up by 4x.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, no I'm using cycles only. Does Eevee speed it up? I'll try that. I'm able to set the samples via python. Thank you

Comment: @ShantanuAryan, no, that won't help me. Because I need depth, flow, and normals at full resolution. I don't want them to be upsampled versions.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN yes Eevee with 1 sample is way faster

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I tried Eevee. Yes, it is indeed faster. But unfortunately, it does not support rendering optical flow (vector). Looks like only cycles supports it

Comment: @NagabhushanSN ah well then theres nothing else u can do except reduce the output resolution.