# Batch rename a .Blend file after the first object or mesh name in the file

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files

After a data crash I have a couple of thousand files like this "f1288357332.blend". I'm not good at python but there must be a way to rename those files as batch after the Object or mesh name in the file. i got the code to rename after the material but not for the object or mesh name. And now i found out there are not only materials in the blend files.

```
import bpy
import os

filepath = bpy.data.filepath
basepath, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
newpath = os.path.join(basepath, "generated")
os.makedirs(newpath,  exist_ok=True)

new_filename = ''
```

and iam a absolut beginner in python - someone here wrote the script
Here is the my question for rename the script after material:

[Batch-Rename-File-after-Material-Slot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272445/batch-rename-a-blend-file-after-the-first-slot-material-with-python)

```
import bpy
import os
import glob
from subprocess import call

BLEND_FILES_DIRECTORY = r"/path/to/your/blend/files" #example path: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\blendfiles
RENAME_SCRIPT = r"/path/to/rename-script.py" #example path: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\blendfiles\rename-script.py

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(BLEND_FILES_DIRECTORY, '*.blend')):
    basepath, filename = os.path.split(file) 
    print("process file:", filename)
    call(['blender','-b', file, '-P', RENAME_SCRIPT])
```

That is the code for rename after the material but i need this to rename after the object file now. Can somebody help me?

Comment: If there is only one object in the scene then you can just get the name of the object with `obj_name = bpy.data.objects[:][0].name` and then substitute that into the rename part of the script, instead of using the material name.

Comment: Look at [this part](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData) of the API to get a better understanding of what you are able to access via `bpy.data`

Comment: you want to rename only after the object name? or also sometimes after the material name? what's the naming priority order?

Comment: Did I miss something, or this was not in the original post? `iam a absolut beginner in python - someone here wrote the script Here the orginal question: [Batch-Reanme](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273349/batch-rename-a-blend-file-after-the-first-object-or-mesh-name-in-the-file)` Plus the link points to the current post.

Comment: @L0Lock Forgive me for having misrepresented the matter in detail. I correct the Topic as good as i can.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie you are the hero of the day i tried it out and it worked. Now after 10000 Materials renamed iam so happy. You are the best!

Comment: @Gibble hey np you're welcome! glad it worked out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy
import os

filepath = bpy.data.filepath
basepath, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
newpath = os.path.join(basepath, "generated")
os.makedirs(newpath,  exist_ok=True)

new_filename = ''

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    new_filename = os.path.join(newpath, o.name + ".blend")
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=new_filename)
    break

if new_filename == '':
    print(filepath, ": Warning no mesh found!")
```

Comment: HarryMCKenzie, you are the hero of the day i tried it out and it worked. Now after 10000 Materials renamed iam so happy. You are the best! Thank you so much! I marked the question as solved!